# JQuery CSS nth-child selector

Tags: jquery, css

I'm facing to very weird behavior of nth-child selector.

When I call function **BackColor1()** my visual looks like:
[image]

What is wrong. And if I call **BackColor2()** everything looks ok.

[image]

Can someone please explain where is the trick and what I have done wrong with **BackColor1()** function?

Here is my sample HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //BackColor1();
        //BackColor2();
    });
    function BackColor1() {
        $("li:nth-child(2n+1) > div").css({ "background": "#F2F2F2" });
    }

    function BackColor2() {
        $("li").each(function (key, val) {                
            if (key % 2 == 0) {
                $(this).children("div").css({ "background": "#F2F2F2" });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>            
    <li>
        <div>Video Streaming</div>
        <ul>                            
            <li><div>VOD</div></li>                            
            <li><div>Progressive Streaming</div></li>                                                                        
        </ul>                            
    </li>                    
    <li><div>Middle Lesson Without Chapter</div></li>                    
    <li>
        <div>File Download</div>                        
        <ul>                            
            <li><div>Direct Download</div></li>                            
        </ul>                            
    </li>                    
    <li><div>Pre Last Lesson Without Chapter</div></li>                    
    <li><div>Last Lesson Without Chapter</div></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I would guess, `li:nth-child(2n+2)` selects every ul seperately, then applies the css to all odd elements in that ul. I have no clue how to get the behaviour you want though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply because `nth-child` is count for each `ul` from the beginning.

```
<ul>            
    <li> <!-- first child of parent ul-->
        <div>Video Streaming</div>
        <ul>                            
            <li><div>VOD</div></li> <!-- first child of nested ul-->
        </ul>                            
    </li>                    
    <li><div>Middle Lesson Without Chapter</div></li> <!-- second child of parent ul-->
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't know that it begins calculations from every parent. After I read w3schools description I thought it selects all li elements and takes only the odd ones.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [even selector](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/)

code:

```
function BackColor1() {
    $("li:even > div").css({
        "background": "#F2F2F2"
    });
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ach9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the VOD item is the first child of its parent, therefore receives the colour. It does not take into consideration other elements around it.

However, your jQuery selector is considering ALL list items on the page as one big group, so it alternates colours no matter where they are in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

BackColor one uses the nth-child selector... Every element's child number is according to its parent so when you nest the lists like that you are prone to face more than one LI element to be treated as nth-child = 1 and so on.